# How to send POST request to a server while app works in background

Tags: android, react-native, post, expo

I have an application that is used for listening to audiobooks.
For statistics purposes, I created a function that sends data every 6 seconds to a server.
With that data, I created a dashboard where I display all the data about books.

This works perfectly on iOS, but on Android it won't work. Is there any tips that you can give me so I can make this work.

I tried with Expo BackgroundFetch, but it didn't work.

This is how my function looks.

```
try {
          await fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'API-KEY': API_KEY,
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              user_token: user.user_token,
              chapter_id: currentChapter?.id,
              time: parseInt(Math.floor(position)),
            }),
          });
        } catch (error) {
          Alert.alert('Error. ', [{ text: 'OK' }]);
        }
```

Comment: What kind of error do you have? I am not familiar with expo framework and didn't touch ReactNative for 6 years, but on native kotlin you have to add ```internet permission``` in Android manifest and web request in non-main thread, then you should get a result. Also please not, your solution is not memory effective at least on Android, too much calls per minute, https://developer.android.com/training/connectivity/network-access-optimization

Comment: Thanks you, I've managed to solve this. But I only managed to send after 1 min, which is acceptable

Comment: Have you set any timeout for requests and responses? what about Websocket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kinda managed to complete it with `Expo` `BackgroundFetch`. I wanted call after 6 seconds, but with `BackgroundFetch` I only got 1 min, which is acceptable.